# connect to oracle which is hosted on different machine

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

Hi I am working on a project in which we have oracle DB that is hosted on one machine and java application on other machine. both machines have UNIX OS.i want to develop a shell script that will use DB query and generate a report but i dont have any client(SQLplus) installed on both the machine. so let me know how can i connect to DB and where shud i develop scirpt like on DB unix machine or application machine.

sqlplus -s "/as sysdba
this is use of sql plus i dont have on any machine..

Comment: You will need *some* kind of SQL client if you want to connect from a shell script. Your options are either to use SQLPlus with an instantclient or use a JDBC based tool that only requires the JDBC driver (and a Java runtime of course)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a shell script?

Comment: there is no other way?? what if i write a C program then?

Comment: in shell script i just want to get some data by using select query and write this into CSV file.

Comment: can we use JDBC tool to connect to DB in shell script if yes then how?

Comment: You can [download the instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) for your platform; you would need the basic (or basic lite) package and the separate SQL*Plus component. And the OCI or JDBC components if you decide to go down one of those routes. You can write a Java tool to get the data and call that from a shell script, since you already semem to have JDBC connectivity for your application?

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh access on both the machines you could run virtually any command(through ssh) you could on the machine itself:

`ssh user@server1 "ls ~/"`

for example the above will give you a listing of files in "user"s home directory on server1..

Comment: how can i connect to database to run the select query and fetch the data by ssh command?

Comment: Its as I've mentioned above, write the command which you want to run within inverted quotes. One thing to consider is that you cannot provide password to DB with the above command.

Comment: should work, could you possibly give the command here, and tell me if you get anything  in the output..